# List Custom Setting retrieval failing - getValues() + getInstance() both return null. Thoughts?

Tags: customsetting

I've been using Custom Settings for a while, and now I'm running into situations where I don't see the results coming back - this setting is one of the first I created, to turn code on & off, although this particular value/reference is new:

The API Name is `NxCode_Switch__c`, and it has values for `Active(Active__c)` and `Debug(Debug__c)`, among others.  I reference it the way I've been doing (although I typically use `.getValues()`):

```
        NxCode_Switch__c callRefAssociation = NxCode_Switch__c.getInstance('Call Reference processing');
        Boolean isActive = (callRefAssociation == null || callRefAssociation.isActive__c == false) ? false : true;
        Boolean bDebug = (callRefAssociation == null || (isActive == false || callRefAssociation.Debug__c == false)) ? false : true;
```

Pretty straightforward.  Both the code & this particular value of custom setting are in the same Sandbox, but now both getInstance() and getValues() are returning null.

I'm using eclipse, API version 31.0, for what that's worth.

Comment: How do you know it is returning null, it should be returning false and have the same result as null in the code you posted. Also is this in a test context?

Comment: If I insert a debug statement after that code and evaluate callRefAssociation it returns null, though there is an NxCode_Switch__c record with that name.  This is whether it's in a test scenario or not.

Comment: If a test context you have to insert the values during the test first. I also believe the name of the instance record is case sensitive. Can you post the debug from `Map<String,NxCode_Switch__c> callRefAssociation = NxCode_Switch__c.getAll();` both from your class and the execution in the dev console